# Real Analysis, Folland Propostion 2.3

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $(X,M)$ is a measurable space and $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the following are equivalent:

a.) $f$ is $M$-measurable

b.)$f^{-1}((a,\infty))\in M \ \ \forall a\in\mathbb{R}$

c.)$f^{-1}([a,\infty))\in M \ \ \forall a\in\mathbb{R}$

d.)$f^{-1}((-\infty,a))\in M \ \ \forall a\in\mathbb{R}$

e.)$f^{-1}((-\infty,a])\in M \ \ \forall a\in\mathbb{R}$

proof a. implies b - Suppose $f$ is $M$-measurable then $f^{-1}(B)\in M$ for all Borel sets $B\subset\mathbb{R}$. Since $(a,\infty)$ is an open set, it is a Borel set, so $f^{-1}((a,\infty))\in M$. Thus a implies b.

Proof b. implies c - Suppose $f^{-1}([a-a/n,\infty))\in M$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $f^{-1}$ preserves intersections, we have $$f^{-1}[a,\infty)) = f^{-1}\left(bigcap_{1}^{\infty}(a-1/n,\infty)\right) = \bigcap_{1}^{\infty}f^{-1}((a-1/n,\infty))\in M$$ and since $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, hence closed under countable intersections. Thus b implies c.

The rest are similar the interesting part of this question is showing that e implies a. Following the same approach as below:

Proof e implies a - Suppose e is true. We want to show that $f$ is $M$-measurable, i.e., that $f^{-1}(B)\in M$ for all Borel sets $B\subset\mathbb{R}$. To do this let $$\varepsilon = \{E\subset\mathbb{R}: f^{-1}(E)\in M\}$$
We need show:

Step 1. $\varepsilon$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Step 2. $\varepsilon$ contains all Borel sets.

This will imply that $f^{-1}(B)\in M$ for all Borel sets $B\subset\mathbb{R}$, proving a.

Proof step 1 - $\varepsilon$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

i.) $f^{-1}(\emptyset) = 0$. Since $\emptyset\in M$ then $\emptyset\in \varepsilon$.

ii.) Let $E\in \varepsilon$, we want to show that $E^c\in \varepsilon$. Now, since $E\in \varepsilon$ then by definition of $\varepsilon$ $f^{-1}(E)\in M$. Note that since $f^{-1}$ preserves complements we have $$(f^{-1}(E))^c - f^{-1}(E^c)\in M$$ Thus $E^c\in\varepsilon$.

iii.) Suppose $\{E_j\}_{1}^{\infty}\subset\mathbb{R}$. We want to show that $\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}E_j\in\varepsilon$. Let $E_j\in \varepsilon$ for all $j$ then by definition of $\varepsilon$ $f^{-1}(E_j)\in M$. Since $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, it is closed under countable unions. So we have, $$\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}f^{-1}(E_j)\in M$$ Since $f^{-1}$ preserves unions, then $$\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}f^{-1}(E_j) = f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}E_j\right)\in M$$ Therefore we have $\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}E_j\in\varepsilon$.

Thus $\varepsilon$ is a $\sigma$-algebra proving step 1.

Proof Step 2 -  $\varepsilon$ contains all Borel sets.

This follows directly from the fact that $\varepsilon$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and using Proposition 1.2, $\varepsilon$ contains all Borel sets.

The last part can be expanded upon, but I think this is clear enough to prove step 2.

Comment: There are some nonsensical sentences in your proof. One is "$f^{-1}$ is $M$-measurable" (what is $f^{-1}$?). Another one is the definition of $E$ (it seems that those are random symbols). Third: it is not clear why you say that $E \subset X$, and then you denote something by $f^{-1} (E)$: this has no sense, as above, since $f$ has $X$ as domain, not codomain. To sum up everything, your proof is a bunch of nonsensical symbols.

Comment: what a blow to my ego...

Comment: @Crostul I re-did my proof, is it still a bunch of nonsensical symbols?

Comment: @MorganWeiss: What does $\bigcup_{1}^{\infty}((a, \infty))$ mean? What variable is being taken from $1$ to $\infty$?

Comment: ok, to fix that can you just say $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}([a - 1/n,\infty))$

Comment: The goal is to show that $(a) \implies (b)$, Suppose $(a)$ is true, so if $f$ is $M$-measurable. This means that $f^{-1}(B) \in M$ for any Borel set $B \subseteq \mathbb R$. Isn't $(a, \infty)$ a Borel set?

Comment: yes, I stated that in my proof

Comment: Well, doesn't that immediately mean $(b)$ is true? I'm not sure what you are doing with the union.

Comment: well I included the union as a crutch I suppose since $f^{-1}$ preserves unions, I thought it would make it easier to see

Comment: To avoid extended discussion in comments, I'll post an answer for the first two implications to get you started, and then a sketch for the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited** to provide more detail for the $(e) \implies (a)$ part of the proof.

---

Suppose $(a)$ is true, so $f$ is $M$-measurable. Recall that this means, by definition, that $f^{-1}(B) \in M$ for every Borel set $B \subset \mathbb R$. Since $(a, \infty)$ is an open set, it is a Borel set, so $f^{-1}((a,\infty)) \in M$, proving $(b)$.

Now suppose $(b)$ is true. Therefore, $f^{-1}((a - 1/n, \infty)) \in M$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$. Since $f^{-1}$ preserves intersections, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
f^{-1}([a,\infty)) &= f^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(a - 1/n, \infty)\right) \\
&= \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}f^{-1}((a - 1/n, \infty))\end{aligned}$$
The right hand side is in $M$ because each $f^{-1}((a - 1/n, \infty)) \in M$ and $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, hence closed under countable intersections. This proves that $(c)$ is true.

For $(c) \implies (d)$, simply observe that $(-\infty,a)$ is the complement of $[a,\infty)$, and use the facts that $f^{-1}$ preserves complements and $M$ is closed under complements.

For $(d) \implies (e)$, use $(-\infty,a] = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\infty, a + 1/n)$ and argue the same way as in $(b) \implies (c)$.

The last part, $(e) \implies (a)$, is the trickiest part. Assuming $(e)$ to be true, the goal is to show that $f$ is $M$-measurable, meaning that $f^{-1}(B) \in M$ for every Borel set $B \subset \mathbb R$.

To do this, we will first show that the collection $\Sigma = \{E \subset \mathbb R : f^{-1}(E) \in M\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\mathbb R$. Then we will show that $\Sigma$ contains all of the Borel sets. This will imply that $f^{-1}(B) \in M$ for all Borel sets $B \in \mathbb R$, proving $(a)$.

**Step 1**: $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra

First, note that $f^{-1}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$, and $\emptyset \in M$ since $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Therefore $\emptyset \in \Sigma$. Similarly, $f^{-1}(\mathbb R) = X$, and $X \in M$, again because $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Therefore $\mathbb R \in \Sigma$.

Now suppose that $E \in \Sigma$. We wish to show that $E^c \in \Sigma$. Since $E \in \Sigma$, by definition of $\Sigma$ this means that $f^{-1}(E) \in M$. Since $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, the complement of $f^{-1}(E)$ is also in $M$. But $(f^{-1}(E))^c = f^{-1}(E^c)$. So $f^{-1}(E^c) \in M$, which means by definition of $\Sigma$ that $E^c \in \Sigma$.

Finally, suppose that $E_1, E_2, \ldots$ is a countable sequence of subsets of $\mathbb R$, such that $E_n \in \Sigma$ for each $n$. Then, again by definition of $\Sigma$, this means that $f^{-1}(E_n) \in M$ for each $n$. Since $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, it is closed under countable unions, so $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}f^{-1}(E_n) \in M$. But $f^{-1}$ respects unions, so $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}f^{-1}(E_n) = f^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n\right) \in M$. This means that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n \in \Sigma$, so $\Sigma$ is closed under countable unions.

Summarizing, we have shown that $\Sigma$ contains $\mathbb R$ and $\emptyset$ and is closed under complements and countable unions. We conclude that $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$ algebra of subsets of $\mathbb R$.

**Step 2**: $\Sigma$ contains all of the Borel subsets of $\mathbb R$

First, note that since $(e)$ is true, $\Sigma$ contains all intervals of the form $(-\infty,a]$. Since $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, it also contains the complements of these intervals, namely the ones of the form $(a, \infty)$. Since $\Sigma$ is closed under intersections, it also contains each interval of the form $(a,b] = (-\infty,b]\cap (a,\infty)$. Since $\Sigma$ is closed under countable unions, it also contains each interval of the form $(a,b) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a,b-1/n]$. Since every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of countably many intervals of the form $(a,b)$, this means that $\Sigma$ also contains all of the open sets. Therefore it also contains all of the Borel sets, because the collection of Borel sets is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all of the open sets. This is exactly what we wanted to prove, so we're done.

Comment: Thanks again for the post, I am on the last part now, and I am having a little trouble understanding how to prove those steps you suggested. Showing the collection $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(E)\in M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra is that not known from propostion 2.1? Also for the Borel part, I thought that was also already known by definition?

Comment: @MorganWeiss: I added a full proof for the last part. Let me know if anything needs clarification.

Comment: P.S. I don't have Folland with me at the moment, so I can't check proposition 2.1 - maybe my proof duplicates it.

Comment: that was really well done, thank you It is completely clear to me but yea with proposition 2.1 you do not need the part before step 1, but it makes the proof more clear